# Prevent Word Wrap In <TD> cell using tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf

I'm converting html tables into PDF's using TCPDF and want to prevent a single  cell from wrapping text.

I have tried `<td style='white-space: nowrap;>` without luck.

Is there a way to force tcpdf to not wrap text within a single `<td>` tag?

Comment: Any chance you found an answer for this?

Comment: No.  I ended up re structuring the document completely using only basic structure elements and CSS.

Answer (score 3):

you didn't close the single single quotes correctly, Please look

```
<td style='white-space: nowrap;>
```

Change this code to

```
$html ='<td style="white-space: nowrap;">';
```

then write this variable to pdf using

```
$this->pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```